# ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'course_id' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL so please tell me if my question is missing information,

I have a query that works fine:

```
select au.email, sm.created, sm.grade, sm.max_grade
from auth_user au, courseware_studentmodule sm
where sm.student_id = au.id
and course_id = 'MyCourse'
and sm.module_type = 'problem';
```

But when I want to add another column from a different table:

```
select au.email, sm.created, sce.created , sm.grade, sm.max_grade
from auth_user au, courseware_studentmodule sm,  student_courseenrollment sce
where sm.student_id = au.id and sm.student_id = sce.id
and course_id = 'MyCourse'
and sm.module_type = 'problem';
```

I get this error

```
ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'course_id' in where clause is ambiguous
```

Anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix an "ambigous column name error using inner join" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029096/how-to-fix-an-ambigous-column-name-error-using-inner-join-error)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the column `course_id` is present in more than two tables.

Write `sm.course_id` or `sce.course_id` and it will work.

Comment: Awesome thanks, QUESTION: since course_id only exists in sm, how come the first query worked  [when I only had two tables]?

Comment: I am sure its only in sm

Answer (score 3):

You are joining multiple tables, at least two of the tables have the column `course_id`. In your statement `and course_id = 'MyCourse'` you are not specifying which table has course_id.

Comment: I did check that actually and only courseware_studentmodule sm
has the course_id column, and when I switch the above to sm.course_id = 'MyCourse'
I just get the same error, I know its strange how the first one works!

Answer (score 2):

`student_courseenrollment` and one of your other tables both have a column called `course_id`. Use a table alias, e.g. `au.course_id`.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the alias of the table with the column of course id in it

like `sce.course_id`

as stated in the comment below this might change your result so use the table name of the table of that is used in the where clause or the alias of that table

Comment: This is almost certainly incorrect; the restriction in the WHERE clause was there before this table was added. As it's not part of the JOIN you may be changing the results.

Comment: But if you look at the first query on the top with only au and sm, the course_id column only exists in sm, but he query works!

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different tables with same column name. If you want to use that column name in any query, you should use with table name Eg:

```
select * from table1,table2 where table1.userId='any id';
```