# Ambiguous Mysql Column

Tags: mysql, ambiguous

**I have this query**

```
SELECT t.employee_id, t.timeinhour,t.timeouthour, 
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t.timeouthour, t.timeinhour)))) 
AS Duration FROM timesheets t 
INNER JOIN employeetimesheets et 
ON t.employee_id=et.employee_id
WHERE employee_id='6748372'
AND timeinyear='2017' 
AND timeinmonth='March' 
AND isWeekNumber='1'
```

**It gives me this error**

> ## 1052 - Column 'employee_id' in where clause is ambiguous

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029096/how-to-fix-an-ambigous-column-name-error-using-inner-join-error) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638520/1052-column-id-in-field-list-is-ambiguous) but I'm not using `all (*)` so I don't understand why?

Comment: Just do `t.employee_id='6748372'`

Comment: You have `t.employee_id` and `et.employee_id`, for you they are the same and hold the same information but MySQL doesn't jump to conclusions, you have to specify which one. Just referencing `employee_id` makes it ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need define table alias in `where` section, like this

```sql
SELECT t.employee_id, t.timeinhour,t.timeouthour,
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t.timeouthour, t.timeinhour))))
AS Duration FROM timesheets t
INNER JOIN employeetimesheets et
ON t.employee_id=et.employee_id
WHERE t.employee_id='6748372'
AND t.timeinyear='2017'
AND t.timeinmonth='March'
AND t.isWeekNumber='1'
```

If column from table `employeetimesheets` set `et` alias

Answer (score 1):

The product of the tables from which you're selecting includes two columns of the same name, as evident here:

```
ON t.employee_id=et.employee_id
```

Both `timesheets` and `employeetimesheets` have that column.  Since the `JOIN` clause will ensure that those two columns in the product will always have the same value, it might not really matter which you specify.  Either one will do the job:

```
WHERE t.employee_id='6748372'
```

Though you may want to run a `DESCRIBE` on both and see if there's any difference in the performance.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify which table you're referring to. Try this instead, and note the updated `WHERE` line:

```
SELECT t.employee_id, t.timeinhour,t.timeouthour, 
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t.timeouthour, t.timeinhour)))) 
AS Duration FROM timesheets t 
INNER JOIN employeetimesheets et 
ON t.employee_id=et.employee_id
WHERE t.employee_id='6748372'
AND timeinyear='2017' 
AND timeinmonth='March' 
AND isWeekNumber='1'
```